# Bloated state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app with a bunch of components with a few similarities:

1. Most components load data from Firebase at construction
2. Most components have an input form that the user can interact with
3. Most components have a simple view

My issue is that the state becomes hard to manage fairly early on as I try to keep all state in the top level component. For instance, I have the component below that let's the user create a new product, add a few images and place a custom marker on one of the images.

My current setup for all components is that there is a currentEntry which represents the entry that the user is currently editing which I initialize with a blank state.

Is it best practice to keep all state in the top component like this or should I rethink my structure?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreateEntryForm from "../../components/entries/createEntryForm";
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import ViewImageDialog from "../../components/entries/viewImageDialog";
import {FirebaseList} from "../../utils/firebase/firebaseList";
import {generateFilename, removeItem, snapshotToArray} from "../../utils/utils";
import {
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import AppBar from "../../components/appBar";
import Spinner from "../../components/shared/spinner";
import firebase from 'firebase';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit*2,
  }
});

const initialFormState = {
  currentProduct: null,
  selectedProducts: [],
  selectedUploads: [],
  selectedMarkedImage: null,
  productQuantity: '',
  locationDescription: '',
  comments: '',
  currentUpload: null,
  username: 'username'
};

const initialFormErrorState = {
  selectProductError: '',
};

class CreateEntry extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      job: null,
      currentEntry: {...initialFormState},
      formErrors: initialFormErrorState,
      uploadLoading: false,
      markedImageLoaded: false,
      attachmentDialogOpen: false,
      openAttachment: null,
      markerPosition: null,
      availableAttachments: [],
      entries: [],
      redirect: false,
      loading: true,
      isEditing: false
    };

    this.firebase = new FirebaseList('entries');

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.setMarker = this.setMarker.bind(this);
    this.handleAttachmentDialogOpen = this.handleAttachmentDialogOpen.bind(this);
    this.saveMarkedImage = this.saveMarkedImage.bind(this);
    this.handleMarkedImageLoaded = this.handleMarkedImageLoaded.bind(this);
    this.handleUploadStart = this.handleUploadStart.bind(this);
    this.handleProgress = this.handleProgress.bind(this);
    this.handleUploadError = this.handleUploadError.bind(this);
    this.handleUploadSuccess = this.handleUploadSuccess.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.firebase.path = `entries/${this.props.match.params.id}`;
    this.jobId = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.entryId = this.props.match.params.entry || null;
    this.firebase.db().ref(`jobs/${this.props.match.params.id}`).on('value', (snap) => {
      const job = {
        id: snap.key,
        ...snap.val()
      };
      this.setState({
        job: job,
        loading: false,
      })
    });
    this.firebase.databaseSnapshot(`attachments/${this.jobId}`).then((snap) => {
      const attachments = snapshotToArray(snap);
      this.setState({availableAttachments: attachments})
    });
    this.firebase.databaseSnapshot(`entries/${this.jobId}`).then((snap) => {
      const entries = snapshotToArray(snap);
      const otherMarkedEntries = entries.filter(entry => entry.id !== this.entryId);
      this.setState({otherMarkedEntries: otherMarkedEntries})
    });
    if (this.entryId) {
      this.firebase.databaseSnapshot(`entries/${this.jobId}/${this.entryId}`).then((entry) => {
        const updatedEntry = Object.assign({...initialFormState}, entry.val());
        this.setState({
          currentEntry: updatedEntry,
          isEditing: !!this.entryId
        })
      });
    }
  }

  validate() {
    const errors = {...initialFormErrorState};
    let isError = false;

    if(this.state.currentEntry.selectedProducts.length === 0) {
      errors.selectProductError = "You must select at least one product";
      isError = true;
    }

    this.setState({formErrors: errors});

    return isError
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    const err = this.validate();
    if(!err) {
      if(this.state.job && this.state.currentEntry) {
        if(!this.state.isEditing) {
          const newEntry = {
            ...this.state.currentEntry,
            'creationDate': Date.now()
          };
          let newEntryRef = this.firebase.db().ref(`entries/${this.jobId}`).push();
          newEntryRef.set(newEntry);
          if (this.state.currentEntry.selectedMarkedImage !== null) {
            this.firebase.db().ref(`attachments/${this.jobId}/${newEntry.currentUpload.id}/markings/${newEntryRef.key}`)
              .set(this.state.currentEntry.selectedMarkedImage)
          }
          this.setState({redirect: 'create'});
        } else {
          const updatedEntry = {
            ...this.state.currentEntry
          };
          const newLogEntry = {
            'lastUpdated': Date.now(),
            'updatedBy': 'username'
          };
          this.firebase.db().ref(`log/${this.jobId}/${this.entryId}`).push(newLogEntry);
          this.firebase.update(this.entryId, updatedEntry)
            .then(() => this.setState({redirect: 'edit'}));
        }
      }
    }
  };

  handleInputChange = name => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;

    if (name === 'currentUpload') {
      this.handleAttachmentDialogOpen(this.state.job.selectedUploads);
    }

    this.setState({ currentEntry: { ...this.state.currentEntry, [name]: value } });
  };

  addSelectedChip = () => {
    if (this.state.currentEntry.currentProduct) {
      const updatedCurrentProduct = {
        ...this.state.currentEntry.currentProduct,
        'productQuantity': this.state.currentEntry.productQuantity
      };
      const updatedSelectedProducts = [...this.state.currentEntry.selectedProducts, updatedCurrentProduct];
      const updatedEntryStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentEntry,
        selectedProducts: updatedSelectedProducts,
        currentProduct: null,
        productQuantity: ''
      };
      this.setState({currentEntry: updatedEntryStatus});
    }
  };

  handleRequestDeleteChip = (data, group) => {
    const itemToChange = new Map([['product', 'selectedProducts'], ['upload', 'selectedUploads']]);
    const selected = itemToChange.get(group);
    const updatedSelectedItems = removeItem(this.state.currentEntry[selected], data.id);
    const updatedEntryStatus = {
      ...this.state.currentEntry,
      [selected]: updatedSelectedItems
    };
    this.setState({currentEntry: updatedEntryStatus});
  };

  handleAttachmentDialogOpen = (attachment) => {
    this.setState({
      attachmentDialogOpen: true,
      openAttachment: attachment
    });
  };

  handleAttachmentDialogClose =() => {
    this.setState({attachmentDialogOpen: false})
  };

  saveMarkedImage() {
    const markedImage = {
      'attachment': this.state.openAttachment[0],
      'position': this.state.markerPosition
    };
    const updatedCurrentEntry = {
      ...this.state.currentEntry,
      'selectedMarkedImage': markedImage
    };
    this.setState({
      currentEntry: updatedCurrentEntry
    });
    this.handleAttachmentDialogClose()
  }

  setMarker(e) {
    const dim = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const position = {
      'pageX': e.pageX - dim.left -25,
      'pageY': e.pageY - dim.top - 50
    };
    this.setState({markerPosition: position});
  }

  handleMarkedImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({markedImageLoaded: true})
  }

  filterProducts(selected, available) {
    if(this.state.job) {
      const selectedProductNames = [];
      selected.forEach(product => selectedProductNames.push(product.name));
      return available.filter(product => !selectedProductNames.includes(product.name))
    }
  }

  handleUploadStart = () => this.setState({uploadLoading: true, progress: 0});
  handleProgress = (progress) => this.setState({progress});
  handleUploadError = (error) => {
    this.setState({uploadLoading: false});
    console.error(error);
  };
  handleUploadSuccess = (filename) => {
    firebase.storage().ref('images').child(filename).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      const getNameString = (f) => f.substring(0,f.lastIndexOf("_"))+f.substring(f.lastIndexOf("."));
      const uploadItem = {"name": getNameString(filename), "url": url, "id": this.generateRandom()};
      const updatedSelectedUploads = [...this.state.currentEntry.selectedUploads, uploadItem];
      const updatedEntryStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentEntry,
        selectedUploads: updatedSelectedUploads
      };
      this.setState({
        uploadLoading: false,
        currentEntry: updatedEntryStatus
      });
    });
  };

  generateRandom() {
    return parseInt(Math.random());
  }

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const filteredProducts = this.filterProducts(this.state.currentEntry.selectedProducts, this.state.job && this.state.job.selectedProducts);
    const title = this.state.isEditing ? "Edit entry for" : "Add entry for";
    const redirectRoute = this.state.redirect
      ? `/entries/${this.props.match.params.id}/${this.state.redirect}`
      : `/entries/${this.props.match.params.id}`;
    return (
      <section>
        <AppBar title={`${title} ${this.state.job && this.state.job.jobId}`} route={`/entries/${this.props.match.params.id}`}/>
        {this.state.loading
          ? <Spinner />
          : <div className={classes.root}>
              <ViewImageDialog open={this.state.attachmentDialogOpen}
                               handleRequestClose={this.handleAttachmentDialogClose}
                               attachment={this.state.currentEntry.currentUpload}
                               setMarker={this.setMarker}
                               markerPosition={this.state.markerPosition || this.state.selectedMarkedImage && this.state.selectedMarkedImage.position}
                               saveMarkedImage={this.saveMarkedImage}
                               markedImageLoaded={this.state.markedImageLoaded}
                               handleMarkedImageLoaded={this.handleMarkedImageLoaded}
                               otherMarkedEntries={this.state.otherMarkedEntries}
              />
              <CreateEntryForm handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                               handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                               availableProducts={filteredProducts}
                               addSelectedChip={this.addSelectedChip}
                               handleRequestDeleteChip={this.handleRequestDeleteChip}
                               job={this.state.job}
                               availableAttachments={this.state.availableAttachments}
                               uploadLoading={this.state.uploadLoading}
                               handleAttachmentDialogOpen={this.handleAttachmentDialogOpen}
                               markedImageLoaded={this.state.markedImageLoaded}
                               handleMarkedImageLoaded={this.handleMarkedImageLoaded}
                               isEditing={this.state.isEditing}
                               handleProgress={this.handleProgress}
                               handleUploadError={this.handleUploadError}
                               handleUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}
                               firebaseStorage={firebase.storage().ref('images')}
                               filename={file => generateFilename(file)}
                               otherMarkedEntries={this.state.otherMarkedEntries}
                               {...this.state.currentEntry}
                               {...this.state.formErrors}
              />
              {this.state.redirect && <Redirect to={redirectRoute} push />}
            </div>}
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CreateEntry);
```

Comment: Your component does way too much. I can see file upload, form handling, some image marking(?), attachments, chips, firebase stuff all in one component. It's as if your one component is your application. I would start by extracting independent/reusable components, and separating them from any state. It's not necessarily a bad practice to keep app state local to components, but at some point you have just too many components just passing state down without doing anything with it, at which point I'd look into using https://github.com/reactjs/redux In your case though, I'd start by refactoring.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful advice. My app is limited by the fact that I need a lot of the local state at the top state component but using Redux might solve exactly this. Would you suggest I can optimize my app without using Redux as well?

Comment: I would love to see an example of how e.g. the chips could be moved to a local state while still saving the input in the handleSubmit. Would this only be possible using Redux?

Comment: Think about how simple html inputs work, you can make your components behave exactly the same way. They can expose an onChange handler, and the parent which manages the application state will update it. This way, your chip components know nothing about application state, but care only about what was being passed via props to them. There are some great tutorials on similar patterns: https://courses.reacttraining.com/courses/advanced-react/lectures/3172720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A centralised global state is a good pattern for state that needs to be global to the whole application. For me, https://redux.js.org/ is the best state engine for react applications.

When I build react/redux applications, I tend to start storing state at the lowest component level I can, and then move it up the component tree and finally into global redux state as and when it is required.

For example, a piece of state that stores whether a div is being hovered over could be stored at component level because it doesn't affect other components, but a piece of state that stores whether a modal is open might need to be in global redux state, because other parts of the application would need to know this.

I would really recommend trying out redux, or at least reading the docs.